# How can I verify that a list elements are in same order of another list or not?

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

list1 [1,2,3,4,5,6] --base list

list2 [1,2,4,3,6,5]

output: 4,6 are in incorrect order

I have to check the order should be as per list1. If not then i have to print all the elements which are not in correct order as per list1.

Comment: What did you try and where did you get stuck?

Comment: Isnt the 3 and 5 also incorrect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stepping through the two lists and printing elements that are different is pretty simple, but it seems you only want to output differing elements once. For this you'd need to keep track of which you'd already seen, e.g. using a `Set`.

```
static void listCompare(List<Integer> list1, List<Integer> list2)
{
    Set<Integer> seen = new HashSet<>();

    int minLen = Math.min(list1.size(), list2.size());
    for(int i=0; i<minLen; i++)
    {
        if(list1.get(i) != list2.get(i) && !seen.contains(list2.get(i)))
        {
            seen.add(list1.get(i));
            System.out.format("%d (%d)%n", list2.get(i), list1.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Test:

```
List<Integer> list1 = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6);
List<Integer> list2 = Arrays.asList(1,2,4,3,6,5);       
listCompare(list1, list2);
```

Output:

```
4 (3)
6 (5)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can compare value of list1 with list2 using list iterator and if compare result gives false then you can print value of list2.